# How to get #EXT-X-ENDLIST event when playing HLS content?

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

According to "Example Playlist Files for use with HTTP Live Streaming: [Basic Variant Playlist](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-BASIC_VARIANT_PLAYLIST)", it describes snippet text below :

> Note: A variant playlist is not re-read. Once the client has read the variant playlist, it assumes the set of variations isn't changing. As soon as the client sees the endlist tag on one of the individual variant, that ends the stream.

but I could not find related APIs to get event for "endlist tag" occur.
Does any one has suggestion to get this event by delegate or function?
Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

### Web

Safari will just fire the `ended` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended) on the HTML5 video element when playback finished.

If you are using third-party players like [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) or [Bitmovin Player](https://bitmovin.com/player/) you may want to check their API; Most of them provide cross-browser convenience functions for this.

### Apps

For native apps on iOS the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` [event](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritemdidplaytoendtimenotification) might be what you want to look at.

Comment: I seek for AVFoundation related API, but thank for your information !

Comment: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification is for playing to the end.
But EXT-X-ENDLIST is sent by content server to describe the streaming is end.
For example, If streaming application has seekbar, and user drag it to begging point periodically, it can not trigger AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, but i can depend seekable duration to know the streaming is end.

Comment: Okay so you are actually asking about an event for when to switch from "live" to "VoD" mode. Is this right?